# removing last 3 characters from a slug in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have this page /free-consultation-sp/ on wordpress

I'm trying to create a dynamic button on that page to go to 
/free-consultation/ by just removing the last 3 characters "-sp"

here is my current code, which only return the current slug

button:

```
<a href="<?php echo the_slug_english(); ?>">English</a>
```

function.php

```
function the_slug_english() {
global $post;
$slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
return $slug; }
```

Is there a way to do this in wordpress? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to use substr:

```
function the_slug_english() {
    global $post;
    $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
    if (substr($slug, -3) == '-sp') {
        $slug = substr($slug, 0, strlen($slug-3));
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

This will strip off -sp from the slug. The substr($slug, -3) gets the last 3 characters from the $slug.